# Docker Unable to install MongoDB Extenstion

Tags: php, mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to install the mongodb php driver in my docker image.

Shorted Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm


RUN pecl install mongodb
RUN echo "extension=mongo.so" > $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/mongo.ini
```

Later in my Dockerfile i try to install a composer application depending on the mongodb extenstion. There I get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongo.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/mongo.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/mongo.so: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/mongo.so.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/mongo.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You named the extension wrong. Instead of `extension=mongo.so` it should be `extension=mongodb.so`. So your example would become:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm


RUN pecl install mongodb
RUN echo "extension=mongodb.so" > $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/mongodb.ini
```

Reference [mongodb installation](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mongodb.installation.pecl.php)

Comment: This solved the problem. Maybe I've read an old documentation about the installing process. Thank you!